# Error The Name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I converted an older web application to a proper web application within VS2008 also using namespaces to be more definitive.

However since doing so i have had an issue where certain fields within my base page are not visible to the code behind page. The biggest issue is of course the Master Page.

I have duplicated the master page and re-typed everything manaually re-creating the Designer file as well and still on both code behind's i get the same error:

> Error 1   The name 'lb_Version' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\SourceControl\JFA Admin
>   Portal\Website\JFA_Admin\MasterPageSimple.master.cs   26  13  JFA_Admin

The master page is as follows:

Base Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPageSimple.master.cs" Inherits="JFA_Admin.MasterPageSimple" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Welcome to JFA Admin</title>
        <meta name="Author" content="Marcus Culver"/>
        <link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="MasterPageSimpleWrapper" class="wrapper">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div id="MasterPageSimpleHeader" >
                    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager> 
                    <br /> <br /> 
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/JFA_Admin.png" CssClass="" />
                    </div>
                    <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lb_Version" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace JFA_Admin
{
    public partial class MasterPageSimple : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_Version.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"] + ": " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ver"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you saw `lb_Version` in intellisense when you write this line? Did you also tried in `Page_Load`

Comment: Sonar, Yes it did show in intellisense. However moving it back to Page_Load and deleting the Designer and re-creating it with Convert to Web Application has indicated a problem with the CC1 tag. Deleting this seems to resolve the issue though :s. Problem is i need the CC1 tag for AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I added a page with the same name as the namespace which was causing a conflict when trying to reference the namespace.

Renamed the page and moved label back to Page_Load (as per Sonar's comment) and all appears to be working again. Even with the CC! tag for script manager.

Base Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="JFA_Admin.MasterPageSimple" Codebehind="MasterPageSimple.master.cs" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Welcome to JFA Admin</title>
        <meta name="Author" content="Marcus Culver"/>
        <link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="MasterPageSimpleWrapper" class="wrapper">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                <div id="MasterPageSimpleHeader" >
                    <br /> <br /> 
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/JFA_Admin.png" CssClass="" />
                    </div>
                    <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lb_Version" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace JFA_Admin
{
    public partial class MasterPageSimple : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_Version.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"] + ": " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ver"];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Sonar Gönül